# MongoDB - Handle error event

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a custom validation when I upload an image to mongoDb. The original name should be unique. If it passes the validation, the code runs properly. But if it fails, it produces error. It says that custom validators that take 2 arguments) are deprecated in mongoose >= 4.9.0. Is there another way to validate the uniqueness of the originalname? Or a way to catch the error? Please help.

```
router.post('/upload',function(req,res){

    Item.schema.path('originalname').validate(function(value, done) {
    Item.findOne({originalname: value}, function(err, name) {
      if (err) return done(false);
      if (name) return done(false);

      done(true);
    });
  });

    upload(req,res,function(err, file) {
        if(err){
          throw err;
        }
        else{
          var path = req.file.path;
          var originalname = req.file.originalname;
          var username = req.body.username;

          var newItem = new Item({
            username: username,
            path: path,
            originalname: originalname
          });

          Item.createItem(newItem, function(err, item){
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(item);
          });

          console.error('saved img to mongo');
          req.flash('success_msg', 'File uploaded');
          res.redirect('/users/welcome');

        }
    });
});
```

model

```
var ItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
username: {
  type: String,
  index: true
},
 path: {
   type: String
 },
 originalname: {
   type: String
 }
});

var Item = module.exports = mongoose.model('Item',ItemSchema);

module.exports.createItem = function(newItem, callback){
  newItem.save(callback);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can provide uniqueness to that field like :-

```
var ItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
username: {
  type: String,
  index: true
},
 path: {
   type: String
 },
 originalname: {
   type: String,
   unique:true    // this string will be unique all over the database
 }
});

var Item = module.exports = mongoose.model('Item',ItemSchema);

module.exports.createItem = function(newItem, callback){
  newItem.save(callback);
}
```

Comment: check whether value is comming null or not while using  `.validate`

Answer (score 0):

To validate uniqueness before saving to db, you can try to `findOne` with tour filename:

```
router.post('/upload',function(req,res){

Item.findOne({originalname: req.file.originalname}, function(err, name) {
       if (err) return done(false); // errors
       if (name) return done(false); // check for existence of item here 

       done(true);
    });
});
```

If findOne function did not respond with any data, it means that, there is no  document in collection with the same original name, and you can proceed with adding document to collection

Comment: no problem, now you can check name if there was no data matching this original name, and if there was no data - proceed to adding to db. Another way is to set filename to random to avoid duplicate file names

Comment: okay :) how about querying two fields at the same time? Like Item.findOne({'two fields here'}). They should be either both TRU or FALSE. just like AND in php.